# Why do nodelists contain extra undefined items that are not reflected in its length property?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nodelist

#### Background:

---

I came across a very strange phenomenon while working with a node list.  I wanted to use getElementsByClassName or something similar and then sort it.  I decided one way would be to iterate through the nodelist and push each item to an array and sort the array. (This did work by the way but not as expected).  I tried using the `for (var i in nodeList)` to iterate through, but it kept throwing an exception on the last few items, which were undefined.  the weird part is I could instead use `for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)` to iterate through.  I just tested it again and on a stackoverflow page I ran in my console the following code:

```
for (var i in document.getElementsByTagName("span"))
    console.count("items");
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("span").length);
```

It counted out to `items: 382` but length gave `380`.  As expected, when I entered `document.getElementsByTagName("span")[380]` and `document.getElementsByTagName("span")[381]` they came back undefined.  This strange behavior does not occur on arrays (granted, nodeLists and arrays are different, but this does prove that it's not the different for loops causing the issue).

#### question:

---

Why does `for(var i in nodeList)` constructs behave differently on nodeLists returning a couple of undefined items at the end?

Comment: *NodeList* objects are array-like. Therefore, don't iterate with `for in`, but with `for`.

Comment: Btw, you can transform a *NodeList* object into a regular array like so: `[].slice.call( nodelist )`.

Comment: Thank you @Šime Vidas but why is this the case?  What causes this strange behavior?  does `for in` just not work for objects?

Comment: I've put an explanation in my answer...

Comment: Thank you again, Šime Vidas. It makes perfect sense now. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two additional properties that the `for in` iteration statement catches are:

- length
- item

Let me give you a simple example. Let's say that there are 3 SPAN elements on the page.

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName( 'span' );
```

Now, `spans` is a *NodeList* object which contains **5** properties:

- 0
- 1
- 2
- length
- item

The first 3 properties are indexes and they contain references to those SPAN elements. The other two properties - length and item - are two additional properties. All *NodeList* objects have these two properties.

The `for in` statement iterates over all 5 properties of the *NodeList* object, which is probably not what you want. Therefore, use a regular `for` statement.

```
var i, span;

for ( i = 0; i < spans.length; i++ ) {
    span = spans[i];
    // do stuff with span
}
```

Comment: That make sense.  Thank you very much for the explanation.  Now I know for next time. :P  Also, thanks for the code snippet of how to convert a NodeList into an array.  It will be immensely helpful in the future.

Comment: @Joseph Note though that that hack doesn't work in IE8 I think. I happen to not care about IE8, so my answers and advice should always be implemented carefully `:)`

Comment: lol I appreciate it in any case. XD I'm always looking for neat little tricks like that.

Answer (score 2):

**for-in** iterates through the *all enumerable properties* of the object such as length and item (this is your situation). This is where two more results come from. It will also enumerate everything added to object prototype.

**for** loops through the numeric indeces and doesn't take into consideration enumerable properties. That is why it much more reliable to use former way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the concise definition.